# Accessing other Functions in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to get the number that I display on the slider value over to my action event where the button is clicked and it runs the mathematical equation for finding tips.

SLIDER

```
@IBAction  func percentageSlider(sender: UISlider) {
    var sliderPercentage = lroundf(sender.value)
    sliderValue.text = "\(sliderPercentage)%"


}
```

BUTTON (Takes slider percentage and calculates it)

```
@IBAction func calculateTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    //1. get total bill
    var userInput = billTextField.text as NSString
    var totalBill : Float = userInput.floatValue

    //2.Determine the tip value

    var tipRate : Float = //HERE SHOULD BE WEHERE THE VALUE FROM THE SLIDER GOES
    var indexString : String = "0.\(tipRate)"
    var index = indexString.toInt()



    //3. Calculate the tip
    var tip : Float = totalBill * tipRate
    //4. Display the tip
    tipLabel.text =  "$\(tip)"
}
```

How can I get the sliderPercentage to appear as a variable in the button function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a slider as IBOutlet. (Drag it in the Interface Builder to code). After that you will be able to access it everywhere in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this, an make sure the slider has the minimum value = 1 and maximum = 100.you can do this in IB.And connect the outlet the the slider

```
@IBOutlet weak var slider : UISlider
@IBAction func calculateTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
//1. get total bill
var userInput = billTextField.text as NSString
var totalBill : Float = userInput.floatValue

//2.Determine the tip value

var tipRate : Float = lroundf(slider.value)
var indexString : String = "0.\(tipRate)"
var index = indexString.toInt()



//3. Calculate the tip
var tip : Float = totalBill * tipRate
//4. Display the tip
tipLabel.text =  "$\(tip)"
```

}

Comment: class AppDelegate: NSObject ,UIApplicationDelegate {           The Debugger highlights this line and says Error code "SIGABRT". It only shows the launch screen and wont go past it

Comment: @user278063 Delete all of your connections,and make those 2